# How create never complete subject of rxjs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

friends. I get a Subject `c`, by dynamic subscribe from other observable object. but want when all observable complete then `c` complete without the first complete.

How can I do this ?

```
const c = new Subject;

const a = Observable.interval(100).take(3).mapTo('a');
const b = Observable.interval(150).take(3).mapTo('b');


a.subscribe(c);
b.subscribe(c);
c.subscribe(console.log);
```

real output

```
a
b
a
a
```

expect

```
a
b
a
a
b
b
```

Comment: `Observable.merge(a, b).subscribe(c);` - don't create multiple subscriptions like that either. Observables can be hard - don't make them any more work than they are :)

Comment: If you really want to use a subject, you can use `multicast` - but meh.

Comment: hi thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum. I want use this subject `c` as a pipe. as a global pipe. so need dynamic subscribe multiple observable.

Comment: I'd still do it statically (with a `merge`), but like I said if you insist I'd use `multicast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behavior because a Subject has an internal state and when it receives the `complete` notification it marks itself as "stopped" and will never ever emit anything. And that's exactly what's happening in you example. When you use `a.subscribe(c)` you're subscribing `c` to all three types of notifications and when the source emits `complete` it's received by `c` as well and it stops emitting.

Instead you can subscribe `c` only to `next` notifications:

```
a.subscribe(v => c.next(v));
b.subscribe(v => c.next(v));
```

Then if you want the source to properly complete when all sources complete you could do the following (you also need to use `share()` on all source Observables):

```
const a = Observable.interval(100)...share();
const b = Observable.interval(150)...share();

...

Observable.forkJoin(a, b)
  .subscribe(() => c.complete());
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be work. but Have rxjs have some elegant style do work for it ?

Comment: Well, what elegant way you expect?